# Finding distribution of a random variable using characteristic functions

Tags: probability-distributions

Random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent with distributions: $P\{X_1=k\}=1/2^k, P\{X_2=k\}=2/3^k, P\{X_3=k\}=4/5^k,k\in\mathbb N.$ Using characteristic functions, find distribution for random variable $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$.

I will show the solution. However, one step I don't understand - I will note that.

Characteristic functions of variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are
$$h_{X_1}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}e^{ikt}/2^k=\frac{e^{it}}{2}\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/2}$$
$$h_{X_2}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}2e^{ikt}/3^k=\frac{2e^{it}}{3}\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/3}$$
$$h_{X_3}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}4e^{ikt}/5^k=\frac{4e^{it}}{5}\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/5}$$
$$h_X(t)=h_{X_1+X_2+X_3}(t)=h_{X_1}(t)h_{X_2}(t)h_{X_3}(t)$$
$$=\frac{4}{15}e^{3it}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-e^{it}/2)(1-e^{it}/3)(1-e^{it}/5)}$$
$$=\frac{4}{15}e^{3it}\left(\frac{5}{1-e^{it}/2}-\frac{5}{1-e^{it}/3}+\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/5}\right)$$

Now, in the following step, I don't understand why the sum goes from zero, when in the definition of a problem, $k\in\mathbb N$ - zero is not specified.
$$$$
$$=\frac{4}{15}e^{3it}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{2^k}-5\cdot\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{1}{5^k}\right)$$

From here, $$P\{X=k+3\}=\frac{4}{15}\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{2^k}-5\cdot\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{1}{5^k}\right); k=0,1,2,...$$

Here, $k$ goes from zero because of the previous step.

My question is: Why $k$ goes from zero in the last step?

Answer (score 0):

You lost $e^{itk}$ when wrote the last step. The formula of geometric series gives
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{itk}/2^k,$$ 
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/3}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{itk}/3^k,$$ 
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/5}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{itk}/5^k,$$ 
and we can write 
\begin{align}
h_X(t)& = \frac{4}{15}e^{3it}\left(\frac{5}{1-e^{it}/2}-\frac{5}{1-e^{it}/3}+\frac{1}{1-e^{it}/5}\right) \cr
& = \frac{4}{15}e^{3it} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{itk}\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{2^k}-5\cdot\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{1}{5^k}\right) \cr & =\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{it(k+3)}\frac{4}{15}\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{2^k}-5\cdot\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{1}{5^k}\right) \cr
& = \sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}e^{itk}\frac{4}{15}\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{2^{k-3}}-5\cdot\frac{1}{3^{k-3}}+\frac{1}{5^{k-3}}\right) 
\end{align}
You can see that $X$ can take values $k=3,4,\ldots$ w.p. 
$$\mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{4}{15}\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{2^{k-3}}-5\cdot\frac{1}{3^{k-3}}+\frac{1}{5^{k-3}}\right).
$$
The smallest value $k=3$ appears when $X_1=X_2=X_3=1$.